# How to Add custom suffix to product attributes in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the product details tab, I want to add the word "tall" to the height attribute.

So instead of **12"** I want **12" tall**

Which template file do I need to edit in order to achieve it or do I need to create a hook and place it in the `functions.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way to achieve it would be by overriding the template `woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php` in your child theme:

Within the `<table>` markup, you need to check if the `$product_attribute_key` matches your height attribute:

```
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">
                <?php 
                    echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); 

                    if ( $product_attribute_key == 'height' ) {
                        echo ' tall';
                    }
                ?>                  
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```